# Data driven test using different XL sheets with different no of parameters

Tags: selenium

Hi i am using data provider for different excel sheets this be done by providing excel sheet name and table name through variable but the problem is that my diff xlsheets  have different parameters i.e no of columns are different and i am providing the no of columns or parameters in test class so when a excel sheet changes my test scripts gets failed is there any way to solve this. Need your help it might solve my big problem

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but the following:

```
MyWorkSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

should return the number of columns used in the excel worksheet "MyWorkSheet". Does this help?